# background color not shown when there is image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create a **canvas** where user can either `add background image` or `background color and write a text` over them. However i could not show background color when there is background image. I have created a **fiddle** of that to show an example. You can try add image and add color button in the fiddle.

http://jsbin.com/sukuvoqahi/edit?html,js,output

Here is my code

```
const canvasRef = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

const addImage = document.querySelector('#addImage');

const addBackgroundColor = document.querySelector('#addBackgroundColor');

addImage.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('image');
  canvasRef.setBackgroundImage('https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg', () => {
    canvasRef.renderAll();
  });
});

addBackgroundColor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('color');
  canvasRef.setBackgroundColor('rgb(100,100,100)', () => {
    canvasRef.renderAll();
  })
});
```

Comment: Well, this is normal. Your background image is big so it covers the background colour. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to show background color on top of image instead of image being top of color.

Comment: I tried to clear the image from canvas and show background color instead when color is choose but this did not work either. You can see pablo.buffer.com where color replaces background image when color is choosen. That is what i am wanting which is not happening.

Comment: @milan — If the image was covered by the background colour, then you wouldn't be able to see the image at all … so just don't add the image!

Comment: @milan you should paste your code for clearing the bg image here so we can see where it went wrong

Comment: @Huangism i was doing canvasRef.backgroundImage = null; inside add color function block but i got it right now. I changed null to 0 and it worked.

Comment: @milan you should check one of the answers at least for their effort

Comment: @Huangism I appreciate their effort and also your reponse. That is why i have not posted my answer instead i am communicating with them to get best idea from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **`backgroundImage`** property to **`null`** or **`0`** for the canvas *(canvasRef)*, before setting the background color ...

```js
const canvasRef = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

const addImage = document.querySelector('#addImage');

const addBackgroundColor = document.querySelector('#addBackgroundColor');

addImage.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('image');
   canvasRef.setBackgroundImage('https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg', () => {
      canvasRef.renderAll();
   });
});

addBackgroundColor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('color');
   canvasRef.backgroundImage = null; //or set 0
   canvasRef.setBackgroundColor('rgb(100,100,100)', () => {
      canvasRef.renderAll();
   })
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350" style="border:1px solid #000000">
</canvas>
<button id="addImage">Add Image</button>
<button id="addBackgroundColor">Add Color</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont think this is the best way. In my understanding, `canvasRef.clear()` clears whole canvas object. If i have text above image, i want background color instead of image then the `canvasRef.clear()` would clear not only image but also text, i think.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that'll clear the whole canvas indeed. Your approach *(commented above)* would be the way to go then :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am marking your answer as solved and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the Backgroud Image.
I am new to FabricJS, so I am not sure if that is the best way to do it.
But this solution seems to work:

```
canvasRef.setBackgroundImage(null) => {
    canvasRef.renderAll();
});
canvasRef.setBackgroundColor('rgb(100,100,100)', () => {
    canvasRef.renderAll();
});
```

Here is a working demo:
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zitaquqero/1/edit?html,js,output)